# transparent toolbar for Navigational Drawer theme of Android Studio with image overlapping toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am a fresher to Android Design. I Have Android Studio's `Navigational DrawerLayout`, when my app loads I'm loading Initial `Fragment` for the app.

1. I want to make the `toolbar` transparent
2. I want to have an image that is overlapping the `DrawerLayout's toolbar`
3. and for other `Fragments` I want the same `toolbar` to be opaque.

First Screen when app Loads

[image]

When any other fragment is called

[image]

Comment: Andof course you "google for this for hours but cannot find a single article", right?

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For No :1.**

All you need to is to define theme which hide action bar, define action bar style with transparent background and set this style to the toolbar widget. Please note that toolbar should be drawen as last view (over all view tree)

```
<style name="Theme.Custom" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Toolbar should be above content-->
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Toolbar layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"/>
```

**For No : 2**

Put ImageView in relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Toolbar should be above content-->
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />


        <ImageView          
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:transitionName="photo_hero"
                android:id="@+id/image"
                />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Toolbar layout:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for a solution, i will try out.  I have a basic question, should i have to use toolbar in every fragment? now i have a common toolbar from  a mainActivity.